# Generating class files similar to EF tt files

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to read specific sections of a file of following format and generate classes, upon which I intend to use EF code first to generate appropriate DB structure and seed data.The file is kinda .txt file with text which is quiet similar to coding style of C#.

Below is sample piece of text from text file :

```
    //PVT
    var PVT1 = new DEMO("DEMO_Ex");
    PVT1.type= "St";
    PVT1.hObj= "None";
    PVT1.wCur= "None";

var PVT2 = new DEMO("default pvt object");
  PVT2.ty ="DemoProperties";
  PVT2.hyObj = "None";
  PVT2.wCur = "None";
  PVT2.Pref = 101;


var STDVOLUME1 = new DEMO_Sample();
  STDVOLUME1.stdardP = 105;
  STDVOLUME1.stdardT = 28.706;

//OPTIONS
var OPT1 = new DEMO_OPT("OPT1");
  OPT1.tempCalc   = "YES";
  OPT1.hTransfer               = "DYNAMIC";
  OPT1.fWall                   = "NO";
  OPT1.feWall               = "NO";

//NUMs
var NUM1 = new DEMO_NUM("NUM1");
  NUM1.tAdv      = 1;
  NUM1.cf        = [1.9];
```

Comment: what is you question?

Comment: Steve- I want to import a file which has text in format that I posted above and want to auto-generate c-sharp classes based on that file and eventually create a DB and seed data into it. so for example the above text that I posted:
That should auto generate classes: DEMO, DEMO_Sample, DEMO_OPT, DEMO_NUM with appropriate properties....same like a json file can be used to generate appropriate C# classes.
Once this is done, I will use EF code first to generate DB and somehow want to use the same file again to seed the DB with data, so based on text above the DEMO table in DB would have 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

ok, what your looking for is T4 Templates, its fully supported in visual studio. right click your project, add-> New Item in the search box type t4, and choose Text Template, not Runtime Text Template. Now youll have to learn about how to write T4 templates as it is beyond this small message box.
They are not to hard to write, I believe I used them once before to generate a static class from a json file and it took me a few hours from never using them before.

Below is a sample t4 that reads a json file and outputs a simple partial class, I have another piece that has code in it to complete the class, but this sample shows you a few things your going to need, like calling c# code to process your file, looping and generating text, when looking at this, keep in mind anything not in <# #> just gets put out to the resulting file

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.ComponentModel" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="Newtonsoft.Json.Linq" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
var file = this.Host.ResolvePath(@"sport_name_map.json");
var json = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(file));
#>
// This is an automatically generated file, based on settings.json and PackageSettingsGen.tt
/* settings.json content:
<#@ include file="sport_name_map.json" #>
*/

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SportMapper
{
    public partial class SportNameMapper
    {
        internal Dictionary<string,object> mapping = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        public SportNameMapper()
        {
        <#
                foreach (var j in json["mapping"].Children()) 
                {
                    var from = j["map_from"].ToString();
                    var to = j["map_to"].ToString();
                    var id = j["sdrm_id"].ToString();
            #>
            mapping.Add("<#= from #>", new {To = "<#= to #>", Id = "<#= id #>"});
            <#
                }
            #>
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Steve,Thanks for your response. If we had a json file, there are lots of online converters available, even visual studio can convert a json file to corresponding classes.
How can we convert the file I posted to a json file ?
If I can convert the above to JSON file, it all becomes very easy for me.
Is there a easy way to do that, because using T4 templates to read that text which I posted would need significant amount of effort..

Comment: I didnt post the code todo what you want, but to show you what t4 can do, you will have to ofcourse write your own